# Preload Images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, preloading

I have been looking into Preloading images with JQuery and came across  this [Preloading images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

Now can someone tell me, do I have to call the preloaded images in any way? I assume this creates a img and then the browser has it cached (at least for that page) and I just use the preloaded image by it's URI?

Can someone clarify here?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The cache is managed by URL.

Comment: Ok so I call the `preload` function and then do something like `$(this).children('img').attr('src', 'http://domain.com/images/icons/rss-12.png');`, then beacuse it's been preloaded, the browser uses the cache?

Comment: Thanks very much. This has helped a lot, and I finally got rid of the hover lag.

Answer (score 4):

Preloading an image can be done with a simple line of JavaScript:

```
new Image().src='image.png';
```

For preloading JavaScript files, use the JavaScript *include_DOM* technique and create a new

[`<script>`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/script) tag, like so:

```
var js = document.createElement('script'); js.src = 'mysftuff.js'; 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
```

Here’s the CSS version:

```
var css  = document.createElement('link');
css.href = 'mystyle.css';
css.rel  = 'stylesheet';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(css);
```

In the first example, the image is requested but never used, so it doesn’t affect the current page. In the second example, the script is added to the page, so as well as being downloaded, it will be parsed and executed. The same goes for the CSS — it, too, will be applied to the page. If this is undesirable, you can still pre-load the assets using XMLHttpRequest.

**For complete tutorial on, "*making your website superfast*" please visit the following link which i hand picked from many websites and blogs**

[Preloading images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the server sets correct cache headers, the image should be cached and you should be able to just use the URL and get the image instantly.

Comment: Ok, by server I assume you mean my hosting server(space)?

Comment: @SeanHJenkins Yes. If you use some generic hosting and serve images as static files the headers are almost always set more or less correctly. In cases where you either generate or server images dynamically etc with PHP script or similar, you might need to set the headers manually. Anyway, chances are you have everything set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can preload all your images using this below:

```
function loadImages(){
    var images = [
        'http://cdn.yourdomain.com/img/image1.png',
        'http://cdn.yourdomain.com/img/image2.jpg',
        'http://cdn.yourdomain.com/img/image3.jpg',
        'http://cdn.yourdomain.com/img/image4.jpg'
    ];
    $(images).each(function() {
        var image = $('<img />').attr('src', this);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I preload a lot using CSS only. I don't like the jQuery versions because you have to wait for the library to be loaded first, and if they don't have JS enabled, or jQuery is delayed, they'll have noticeable image change delays on rollover.

If you need a callback when images have finished preloading, use JS/jQuery. Otherwise, use CSS.

This is just one method which uses `:before`, so has browser support limitations (< IE8). The good thing about this one is you dont need any extra HTML markup.

**HTML**

```
<div class="logo"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.logo {
    background:url(logo-1.png);
}

.logo:before {
    content: url(logo-2.png);
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Another method would be to simply set background images to hidden elements on your page with the images you need to preload.

**HTML**

```
<div id="preload-logo-2"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#preload-logo-2 {
    background: url(logo-2.png);
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```