# How to stop images from flashing as they change on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Is there anyway to stop my images from flashing as they reload new ones?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YShs2/149/)

Here is the code that I'm using to swap images out `onmouseover` but as before it loads the new image, it quickly flashes and shows the divs background colour:

JS:

```
function chbg(img) {
    document.getElementById('navholder').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+img+')'; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="index.html"><div id="button1" onmouseover="chbg('http://placehold.it/300x250')" onmouseout="chbg('http://placehold.it/950x350')"><div id="triangle"></div><div id="buttonname">Home</div></div></a>
```

Comment: Yes. [Preload your images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504764/preload-images).

Comment: Ah brilliant, I thought this was the case but I wasn't sure how to go about it. I'll check it out

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
var arrayOfImages = [
    'img/imageName.jpg',
    'img/anotherOne.jpg',
    'img/blahblahblah.jpg'
]
```

Actually loads the images into DOM and hides it by default.

```
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function () {
        $('<img />').attr('src',this).appendTo('body').css('display','none');
    });
}
```

Comment: n.b. requires jQuery.

Comment: Images are still flashing when I use this code.. even with jQuery

Comment: I can see it flashing in the fiddle. If you move the mouse on and off "home" you see it quickly flash white as it reloads the image.

Comment: OK, sometimes it doesn't flash with the placeholder images but when I use local images, it flashes

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phKe6/10/)

1.- stack invisible divs over the original background

```
<div id="button1_related"></div>
<div id="button2_related"></div>
```

2.- mouseover/mouseout show/hide divs, there is no image loading (and no flashing)

```
function nowshow(id) {
  document.getElementById(id+'_related').style.display = 'block'; 
}
function nowhide(id) {
  document.getElementById(id+'_related').style.display = 'none'; 
}
```

3.- ...and you control the img in the css.

```
#button1_related{
position:absolute;display:none;
top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;
background-image: url('http://placehold.it/300x250');
}
#button2_related{
position:absolute;display:none;
top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;
background-image: url('http://placehold.it/340x150');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use css

```
#button1 {
   background-image:url('<!-- Your url here-->');
}
#button1:hover {
   background-image:url('<!-- Your url here-->');
}
```

Use sprites for rollover images. This will take out any flashes and will save http requests making your website faster:

http://spritepad.wearekiss.com/

Comment: This won't change the background of a another div, only button1.