# JavaScript onClick change image in canvas compatibility

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, onclick, cross-browser

I make some CODE to change images in CANVAS on selecting item from dropDown list.
It working as it should in IE but in Chrome and FireFox when I chose item from dropDown list nothing happened until I click on dropDown list again.
Here is [link to sample](http://www.aantdesign.in.rs/_tosha/index.html):
Here is CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body{ margin:40px; background:#666; }
    #my_canvas{ background:#FFF; border:#000 1px solid; }
</style>
<script>
    var text = "";
    var i;
    var slika01 = new Image();
    var slika02 = new Image();
    var slika03 = new Image();
    slika01.src = "images/sloj01_01.png";
    slika02.src = "images/sloj02_01.png";
    slika03.src = "images/sloj03_01.png";

function clear(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 300);
}
function draw(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
    //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 300);
    ctx.drawImage(slika01, 0, 0, 500, 300); // Positioning, sizing
    ctx.drawImage(slika02, 0, 0, 500, 300); // Positioning, sizing
    ctx.drawImage(slika03, 0, 0, 500, 300); // Positioning, sizing
}
function osvezi01(vrednost){
        slika01.src = "images/sloj01_0" + vrednost + ".png";
        clear();
        draw();
    }
function osvezi02(vrednost){
        slika02.src = "images/sloj02_0" + vrednost + ".png";
        clear();
        draw();
    }
function osvezi03(vrednost){
        slika03.src = "images/sloj03_0" + vrednost + ".png";
        clear();
        draw();
    }

window.onload = draw;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="my_canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
<p>
<label for="slikai01">slikai 1. sloja</label>
<select name="slikai01" id="slikai01" onClick="osvezi01(this.value);">
<script>
    text = "";
    for (i = 1; i<=5; i++){
        text += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
    }
    document.getElementById("slikai01").innerHTML = text;
</script>
</select>
<label for="slikai02"> | slikai 2. sloja</label>
<select name="slikai02" id="slikai02" onClick="osvezi02(this.value);">
<script>
    text = "";
    for (i = 1; i<=5; i++){
        text += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
    }
    document.getElementById("slikai02").innerHTML = text;
</script>
</select>
<label for="slikai03"> | slikai 3. sloja</label>
<select name="slikai03" id="slikai03" onClick="osvezi03(this.value);">
<script>
    text = "";
    for (i = 1; i<=5; i++){
        text += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
    }
    document.getElementById("slikai03").innerHTML = text;
</script>
</select>
</p>
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You can try to use the `onchange` event instead of the `onClick` event for your dropdowns.</strike>

I rebuilt the environment locally and it runs for me. I tested it with the links to your images on your server so I guess the preloading works.

What I did is that I changed the `onClick` to the `onchange` event and added the preloading of all images.

I also split up the source code into three different files and merged the three dropdown event functions to one function and added a parameter instead. But those two changes are not necessary to solve the problem. The first two changes are enough.

Here is the source code:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="my_canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
<p>
<label for="slikai01">slikai 1. sloja</label>
<select name="slikai01" id="slikai01" onchange="redraw(this.value, 1);">
    <script>
        text = "";
        for (i = 1; i<=5; i++){
            text += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
        }
        document.getElementById("slikai01").innerHTML = text;
    </script>
</select>
<label for="slikai02"> | slikai 2. sloja</label>
<select name="slikai02" id="slikai02" onchange="redraw(this.value, 2);">
    <script>
        text = "";
        for (i = 1; i<=5; i++){
            text += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
        }
        document.getElementById("slikai02").innerHTML = text;
    </script>
</select>
<label for="slikai03"> | slikai 3. sloja</label>
<select name="slikai03" id="slikai03" onchange="redraw(this.value, 3);">
    <script>
        text = "";
        for (i = 1; i<=5; i++){
            text += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
        }
        document.getElementById("slikai03").innerHTML = text;
    </script>
</select>
</p>
</body>
```

**style.css**

```
body {
    margin:40px;
    background:#666;
}

#my_canvas {
    background:#FFF;
    border:#000 1px solid;
}
```

**script.js**

```
new Image().src = "images/sloj01_01.png";
new Image().src = "images/sloj01_02.png";
new Image().src = "images/sloj01_03.png";
new Image().src = "images/sloj01_04.png";
new Image().src = "images/sloj01_05.png";

new Image().src = "images/sloj02_01.png";
new Image().src = "images/sloj02_02.png";
new Image().src = "images/sloj02_03.png";
new Image().src = "images/sloj02_04.png";
new Image().src = "images/sloj02_05.png";

new Image().src = "images/sloj03_01.png";
new Image().src = "images/sloj03_02.png";
new Image().src = "images/sloj03_03.png";
new Image().src = "images/sloj03_04.png";
new Image().src = "images/sloj03_05.png";

var slika01 = new Image();
slika01.src = "images/sloj01_01.png";
var slika02 = new Image();
slika02.src = "images/sloj02_01.png";
var slika03 = new Image();
slika03.src = "images/sloj03_01.png";

function clear() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 300);
}

function draw(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById('my_canvas').getContext('2d');
    //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 300);
    ctx.drawImage(slika01, 0, 0, 500, 300); // Positioning, sizing
    ctx.drawImage(slika02, 0, 0, 500, 300); // Positioning, sizing
    ctx.drawImage(slika03, 0, 0, 500, 300); // Positioning, sizing
}

function redraw(vrednost, num){
    switch(num) {
        case 1:
            slika01.src = "images/sloj01_0" + vrednost + ".png";
            break;
        case 2:
            slika02.src = "images/sloj02_0" + vrednost + ".png";
            break;
        case 3:
            slika03.src = "images/sloj03_0" + vrednost + ".png";
            break;
    }
    clear();
    draw();
}

window.onload = draw;
```

Comment: I try that first but I got worst results than with onClick in google Chrome and FireFox browsers. I make clear() function in order to overcome that problem but without success. Open link I post to see that problem in vivo.

Comment: I think I figured something out. Also I don't think it is a cross-browser problem. Just click every item in the dropdown menus once. After clicking all of them there is no more problem when clicking them again. I think the problem there is, that the images need a little bit to load.

Comment: You are wrong - in IE it work as a charm - when I chose item from dropDown menu it instantly change image, but in Chrome and FireFox I need to click twice on dropDown menu to change image in canvas.

Comment: Have you tried to clear your cache in IE? After I did this I got the problem again. - As a solution I would suggest to preload all of the images or draw the rectangles instead of drawing them from pictures. For  preloading there is the `onLoad` event for `Image` objects which can be used to check if an image was loaded.

Comment: I found [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504764/preload-images) where it says you simply can preload images like this `new Image().src='image.png';`

Comment: I use those rectangles just for testing - instead of them I'll use pictures. I'll try with preload and report. Thanx in any way.

Comment: I try with preload images but I got same result.  :(

Comment: I rebuilt the environment locally and added the results in the answer.

Comment: It work as a charm. Thanx mate. I hawe one more question - instead of these 5 picture I'm gonna have 500 pictures for every layer (1500 pictures in sum). Can I preload all those pictures in some FOR loop ?

Comment: I am glad I could help!

Comment: i want to do the same thing but change the canvas image on click event. Also using angularjs. Is there any demo or link for reference.? It's your great help to me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The following line shows where ```redraw``` gets called: ```<select name="slikai03" id="slikai03" onchange="redraw(this.value, 3);">```. So if you want to use some click event to trigger it simply add ```onclick="redraw(this.value, 3);"``` to the element that should be the clickable trigger.